# Accessing mediaelement in listbox wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a MediaElement inside ListBox.How I can get access to "audiop_Copy" by buttons "play/pause"?

```
<local:TypeTemplateSelector.WithAudio>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="0,5">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock ... />
        <StackPanel Height="50" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,4,0" MinHeight="50">
          </TextBlock>
          <Button Click="PlayMedia" Content="Play" />
          <Button Click="PauseMedia" Content="Pause" />
        </StackPanel>
        <MediaElement Name="audiop_Copy" Source="{Binding audioUri}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoPlay="False"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</local:TypeTemplateSelector.WithAudio>
```

Comment: Is your problem that you do not have a way to determine which MediaElement you should be manipulating since there are many in the listbox? One way to accomplish it is to use Tag property on your controls.

Comment: There may be around 100 items.I need to create mediaPlayer.

Comment: I can't get audiop_Copy for manipulating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways to do it from the spot (possibly there are more). You will need a pointer to your Button that was clicked anyway:

1. [difficult, inflexible, fragile] In button Click event handler use **VisualTreeHelper** class to navigate Visual Tree and find the element. Use sender as starting point
2. [better solution] use Tag property and binding.

   ```
   <Button Click="PauseMedia" Content="Pause" Tag={Binding ElementName=audiop_Copy} />
   ```

And in handler something like that:

```
private void PauseMedia(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var me = ((FrameworkElement) sender).Tag as MediaElement;
}
```